# Deploy console application via Nuget

Tags: .net, deployment, nuget, installation, azure-devops

I want to deploy a console application via Nuget (so it can be easily consumed in a VSTS hosted build agent).

I am using the `install` command from the `nuget.exe` CLI.

This results in my package and its dependencies being installed, however all they are all installed in their respective nuget package folders. E.g:

- MyApp/Lib/net641/My.exe
- SomeDependency/Lib/net/Dependency.dll
- ...

And not in a standard release build structure.

- Release/My.exe
- Release/Dependency.dll
- Release/...

This means when I execute my application I get lots of `Could not load file or assembly` exceptions as my dependencies arn't in the same folder as my exe.

I can see two obvious ways to resolve this:

1. Change my package to ship as a single release folder with all the dependencies included 'manually', and don't use nuget to resolve those dependencies normally.
2. Use something like PowerShell to manually move all the files around after `install`.

I wanted to check their wasn't some other option or nuget command I could use which would be more straight forward.

Comment: I don't think there is the other easy way to do it.

Comment: I suggest that you can change the source (e.g. path of My.exe) in target app, because it's easy for others to use this package without to do other things.

Comment: What's the file structure of your console application project and how do you generate the nuget package for it?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT its a fairly standard console app, single assembly with a number of references. Currently building the nuget using a VSTS pack task on a nuspec file.

Comment: How did you add the reference? If it is a class library project reference by the console application project, you can use "nuget pack -IncludeReferencedProjects" command.

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT references are all via Nuget

Comment: Then there isn't any other option to achieve this.